# alfresco attachments java backend

Tags: java, javabeans, document, attachment, alfresco

Can anyone tell me how I can access the "attachments" property under "assocs" of a
AlfrescoDocument in my java backend bean? I've searched through Google and the forum
but couldn't find anything. It seems that there is no function of the
document variable that is doing that job.

Thanks

Comment: What class / api are you working with?

Comment: I'm working with cmis so the document is a org.alfresco.cmis.client.AlfrescoDocument

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache Chemistry developers guide](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html) and [developing guide](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/index.html) to learn how the Java CMIS API works, how to traverse etc?

Comment: do you want to get the associated documents?you can certainly do that.Do you have access to services of alfresco in your bean?

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to do it, the key was indeed to use the alfresco session instead of trying to find a function for the Alfresco Document instance.
For other people trying to do that:
alfrescoSession.getRelationships(...); will do what is wanted.
Thanks for the help